# AES encryption in C Sharp and decryption in Android using PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1

Tags: c#, android, cryptography, aes, pbkdf2

I am using Android and I am trying to decrypt a message encrypted in a C Sharp Server.

Below is the code for the C# Cryptor, that uses 256 bit long Keys, 128 bit long IV, 5000 Iterations. It uses **Rfc2898DeriveBytes Class**, so that is the same as **PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1** in Android.

The decrypt function of the C# Cryptor takes as its IV the (reversed) first 128 bits of the 256 bit long key.

```
namespace CompanyName.Framework.Encryption
{
    internal class SymmetricCryptor : ISymmetricCryptor
    {
        internal static int KeyLengthInBytes = 32; 

        internal int Iterations = 5000; 

        #region Private Fields
       // RijndaelManaged aes; old version
        AesManaged aes;
        int IVLength = KeyLengthInBytes >> 1;
        #endregion Private Fields

        #region Internal Constructors

        internal SymmetricCryptor( )
        {

            aes = new AesManaged
            {
                Mode = CipherMode.CBC,
                KeySize= KeyLengthInBytes<<3,
                Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7,


            };
            //aes.KeySize = KeyLengthInBytes << 3;
            //aes.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros; //PKCS7 can not be used with stream
        }

        #endregion Internal Constructors

        #region Public Methods

        public byte[] Decrypt(byte[] cryptedData, string password, IVMode ivmode)
        {
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(cryptedData))
            {
                using (MemoryStream data = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    Decrypt(ms, data, password,ivmode);
                    return data.ToArray();
                }
            }

        }


        public void Encrypt(Stream data, Stream trgStream, string password, IVMode ivmode)
        {

            try
            {

                var key = GetKey(password);


              var iv  = (ivmode == IVMode.Auto)
                  ?key.GetBytes(IVLength).Reverse().ToArray()
                  :                  new byte[IVLength];

                var dc = aes.CreateEncryptor(key.GetBytes(KeyLengthInBytes), iv);

                using (CryptoStream cryptor = new CryptoStream(trgStream, dc, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {

                    data.CopyTo(cryptor);
                    cryptor.FlushFinalBlock();
                    cryptor.Close();
                }


            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Invalid password.");
            }
        }


        public void Decrypt(Stream cryptedData, Stream trgStream, string password, IVMode ivmode)
        {


             try
            {

               var key= GetKey(password);

               var iv = (ivmode == IVMode.Auto)
                 ? key.GetBytes(IVLength).Reverse().ToArray()
                 : new byte[IVLength];
               var dc = aes.CreateDecryptor(key.GetBytes(KeyLengthInBytes),iv);

                    using (CryptoStream cryptor = new CryptoStream(cryptedData, dc, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                    {

                        cryptor.CopyTo(trgStream);

                        cryptor.Close();
                    }


            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Invalid password.");
            }
        }

        public byte[] Encrypt(byte[] data, string password, IVMode ivmode)
        {
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(data))
            {
                using (MemoryStream cData = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    Encrypt(ms, cData, password,ivmode);
                    return cData.ToArray();
                }
            }
        }

        #endregion Public Methods

        #region Private Methods

        private Rfc2898DeriveBytes GetKey(string password)
        {
            try
            {
                var iv =
                    CompanyName.Framework.Cryptography.Digest.SHA1.Compute(password);

                return new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, iv, Iterations);


            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        #endregion Private Methods


    }
}
```

My Android Cryptor, which tries to decrypt a message encrypted by the above C Sharp Cryptor looks like this, I tried to copy the Decrypt method of the C Sharp Cryptor:

```
public class Cryptor {

private static final String TRANSFORMATION = "AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding";
private static final String AES = "AES";
private static final String RANDOM_ALGO = "SHA1PRNG";
private static final int KEY_LENGTH_IN_BITS = 256;
private static final int IV_LENGTH = 16;
private static final int PBE_ITERATION_COUNT = 5000;
private static final int PBE_SALT_LENGTH_INT_BITS = 128;
private static final String PBE_ALGO = "PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1";


public static byte[] generateKeyFromPassword(String password, int Size) throws GeneralSecurityException {
    byte[] salt = generateSalt();
    KeySpec keySpec = new PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray(), salt, PBE_ITERATION_COUNT, Size);
    SecretKeyFactory keyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(PBE_ALGO);
    byte[] data = keyFactory.generateSecret(keySpec).getEncoded();
    return data;
}

private static byte[] generateSalt() throws GeneralSecurityException {
    return randomBytes(PBE_SALT_LENGTH_INT_BITS);
}

private static byte[] randomBytes(int length) throws GeneralSecurityException {
    SecureRandom random = SecureRandom.getInstance(RANDOM_ALGO);
    byte[] b = new byte[length];
    random.nextBytes(b);
    return b;
}

public static byte[] decrypt(byte[] cipherText, String password) throws GeneralSecurityException {
    byte[] keyBytes = generateKeyFromPassword(password, 256);
    byte[] ivBytes = generateKeyFromPassword(password, 128);


    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(TRANSFORMATION);

    ivBytes = reverse(ivBytes);

    SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, AES);
    IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(ivBytes);

    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey, ivSpec);

    byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(cipherText);
    return decrypted;
}


public static byte[] reverse(byte[] array) {
    if (array == null) {
        return null;
    }
    int i = 0;
    int j = array.length - 1;
    byte tmp;
    while (j > i) {
        tmp = array[j];
        array[j] = array[i];
        array[i] = tmp;
        j--;
        i++;
    }
    return array;
}
```

But it is not working, When do final is called I get a

```
javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: error:1e06b065:Cipher functions:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:BAD_DECRYPT
```

Exception. I am not sure what I am doing wrong, because my Decrypt Method in Android is doing the exact same thing as the Decrypt Method in C Sharp: First I generate a Key from the password, which is shared by the Csharp Server and me. Then I generate a random 128 bit IV, reversing it is not necessary, but C Sharp implementation reverses it, so I do it as well. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? Here is the context where I use the Cryptor:

```
//open the client channel, read and return the response as byte[]
Channel clientChannel = new Channel(serverAddress);
byte[] result = clientChannel.execute(serviceID.toString(), data);

//result[] is encrypted data. firstTen is the shared Password
byte[] decrypted = Cryptor.decrypt(result, firstTen);
```

Server returns the result as Base64 encrypted, before passing it for decryption I get the result[] array through:
It comes as a Base64 String. I get  the result[] array through:

```
Base64.decode(result, Base64.NO_WRAP);
```

Comment: Instead of trying to find the difference between C# and Android, you're better off first fixing your encryption problems. The initialization vector should be random data and not depend on the password. Otherwise, it cannot fulfill its purpose as the same plain text and password will always lead to the same output. PBKDF2 was built for hashing a password that needs to be stored. When you derive the salt from the password, you defeat the purpose of salting. And in the current context, I don't see any need for PBKDF2 at all. At what is `Reverse` for? Do you think it increases security?

Comment: Yes you are right, I already updated my code and now generate a 128 bit IV at random. In the C Sharp Code it is already generated at random. But I still get the mentioned Exception. What do you mean you don't see the need for PBKDF2. We have a shared Password with the C Sharp server, and I need to generate a Key and IV using this shared Password? How can I do it other than using PBKDF2? Reversing is not necessary but the server did it, so I did it as well. The C sharp code is not my code, Java code is my code

Comment: If you generate a salt or IV using the password, you haven't understood the purpose of the salt and IV. It defeats its very purpose. Please study the basics of encryption and revisit your design. (Sorry for being so blunt...)

Comment: @Codo The `salt` is generatted by `randomBytes()` not `PBKDF2`.

Comment: @zaph: Yes, now it is. It was different in the original question. See http://stackoverflow.com/posts/35865222/revisions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to generate random salt and IV on Server side and sent it with ciphreText to Android side. Android need to use exactly the same salt and IV to derive key for decryption that that was used to derive encryption key on Server side.

Comment: Also send the iteration count.